# Angular, fallo al querer exportar class

Tags: angular, class

Recién estoy comenzando a aprender a usar Angular, estoy teniendo un pequeño problema con un ejercicio sencillo, que no logro de entender.

Se trata de querer exportar una Class.

Desde el archivo app.component.ts y que se vea en app.component.html 
Lo estoy haciendo exactamente igual pero no se reflejan los cambios.

Código en **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',

})

  export class AppComponent {

  nombre:string = " David ";  
  apellido:string = " Torre ";
}
```

(nombres solo de ejemplo)

y se deberían de ver aquí:

Código en **app.component.html**

```
<h1> Nombre: </h1> 
<h3> Apellido: </h3>
```

Al guardar los cambios, se actualiza el navegador pero no aparece ni el nombre ni el apellido, es decir, el app.component.html no lee la class o algo me falta.

Agradecería su ayuda.

Saludos! :)

Comment: no te falta en el html algo como {{nombre}}??

Comment: La verdad, no lo sé, estoy siguiendo un curso y lo hago exactamente igual que el que me está enseñando, tengo el código igual que él.

Comment: Marco es muy importante que no pongas un comentario que diga gracias, si no que aceptes la respuesta que resuelve tu problema. Se agradecen los comentarios de gracias, pero es mucho mejor aceptar la respuesta que sirvio, y votar positivo tambien respuestas que esten correctas.

Answer (score 5):

Cambia tu vista actual :

```
<h1> Nombre: </h1> 
<h3> Apellido: </h3>
```

por esto :

```
<h1> Nombre:{{nombre}} </h1> 
<h3> Apellido:{{apellido}} </h3>
```

Estas asignando valores a tus dos variables pero en ingun momento le estas pasando dichas variables a la vista, la forma de hacer es la siguietne: `{{nombreVariable}}`

Answer (score 2):

Las variables que declares en tu archivo ".TS" debes extrapolarlas en el archivo .HTML.
Ejemplo:

```
<h1> Nombre:{{nombre}} </h1> 
<h3> Apellido:{{apellido}} </h3>
```

Con eso aparecerán todos los cambios generados en tu componente.
Suerte!